# I cannot use Debug on IntelliJ : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder.getSingleton()'

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, nosuchmethoderror

I am working on Spring Boot and getting NoSuchMethodError when I click on Debug.
Apparently it is caused by multiple slf4j bindings in the classpath.
It all happened all of a sudden and I am not able to fix this for over a week now.

Please see the attached stacktrace.

My maven dependency tree is pasted below showing the different loggers on the list.

```
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  | \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  | \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be many breakpoints

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. I removed all breakpoints and now everything is fine.   
To remove all breakpoints in IntelliJ Idea press following sequence of shortcuts:
Ctrl + Shift + F8 (open Breakpoints dialog)
Ctrl + A (select all breakpoint)
Alt + Delete (remove selected breakpoints)
Enter (confirm)